# Do distances measured in light years account for length contraction?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

If there's a galaxy that's 1 light year away from Earth, I should see a spaceship traveling at C/2 get there in 2 years, right?

However, someone riding on said ship should measure a shorter trip time due to space being length contracted during the trip.

How is this discrepancy solved?

Also, due to length contraction, the distance gone in time T going at C/2 should be more than twice the distance gone in the same time T going at C/4, right?

However, I don't think this is the case.
Can anyone clarify?

Comment: One thing, the spaceship cannot travel at c, close to it, but not exactly at c so long as it has mass.

Comment: I think that it is what SR is for. However when we said galaxy x is y ly away we just mean that its light started its journey y years ago.

Comment: @Triatticus yeah, the speed was meant to be C/2. That's why the trip took 2 years, not 1. My mistake.

Comment: BTW, galaxies are a lot further away than 1 light-year! The diameter of the Milky Way is about 100 thousand light-years, and the nearest large galaxy, Andromeda, is about 2.5 million light-years away.

Comment: On the *very* large scale, specifying distances gets tricky because of the expansion of space, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_measures_(cosmology)). For small interstellar distances, we can ignore all relativistic effects because they're so small (they only become significant when relative speeds are getting near *c*).

Answer (score 0):

> However, someone riding on said ship should measure a shorter trip time due to space being length contracted during the trip.
>
> How is this discrepancy solved?

The discrepancy is what relativity predicts will happen. There is time dilation, so the person in the ship experiences less time.